# How to build Qt5 without webengine?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt5

Following is the result of building Qt5 from source on macOS. It takes 31G, from which 27G are from webengine. Unfortunately I didn't tracked the build time but it's many hours.

I think I don't need webengine for my application. And I guess build will be much quicker (and smaller) without it.

How to remove `webengine` from the build?

```
$ du -h -d 1 qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7
6.7M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwebsockets
 30M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtquickcontrols
 10M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtserialbus
3.2M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtgamepad
3.7M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwebview
332M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtdeclarative
3.1M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtmacextras
2.7G    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtbase
 20M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtsvg
1.3M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtandroidextras
2.6M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtactiveqt
 17M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtremoteobjects
3.5M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtpurchasing
 18M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtsensors
3.1M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwinextras
 32M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtcanvas3d
 26M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtconnectivity
4.1M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtnetworkauth
 16M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtdoc
4.2M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/gnuwin32
2.6M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtspeech
 47M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtscript
 46M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtcharts
 20M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtgraphicaleffects
2.7M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/coin
1.9M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/config.tests
5.8M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtserialport
 41M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtvirtualkeyboard
2.7M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtx11extras
 27G    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwebengine
5.0M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwebchannel
1.9M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwebglplugin
 18M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qttranslations
6.7M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtwayland
 68M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtmultimedia
 69M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtquickcontrols2
115M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtlocation
 90M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qttools
412M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qt3d
 39M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtxmlpatterns
 34M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtdatavis3d
 13M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtscxml
 14M    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7/qtimageformats
 31G    qt-everywhere-src-5.12.7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can skip modules with `-skip qtwebengine` as argument for configure:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#excluding-qt-modules